# How to keep folder structure while converting, resizing, and moving images using powershell

Tags: powershell, resize, move

I am trying to write a powershell script that will take a param of a source directory, iterate through it and convert all images to .jpg, resize them and then move them to a new directory, while keeping their sub directory structure.

Right now I have a script that will do everything except maintain folder structure so.

```
param([String]$src)
#param([String]$src, [string]$dest)
#param([String]$src, [string]$dest, [switch]$keepSubFolders)

Import-Module '\Convert-ImgageType.ps1'
Import-Module '\Set-ImageSize.ps1'

Get-ChildItem "$src\*" -include *.tif -Recurse | Convert-ImgageType -Destination $src\* -Verbose
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Get-ChildItem "$src\*.jpg" | Set-ImageSize -Destination $src -WidthPx 9000 -HeightPx 6000 -Verbose 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Remove-Item "$src\*.jpg" -Verbose
```

```
Set-ImageSize.ps1
Function Set-ImageSize
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Resize image file.

    .DESCRIPTION
        The Set-ImageSize cmdlet to set new size of image file.

    .PARAMETER Image
        Specifies an image file. 

    .PARAMETER Destination
        Specifies a destination of resized file. Default is current location (Get-Location).

    .PARAMETER WidthPx
        Specifies a width of image in px. 

    .PARAMETER HeightPx
        Specifies a height of image in px.      

    .PARAMETER DPIWidth
        Specifies a vertical resolution. 

    .PARAMETER DPIHeight
        Specifies a horizontal resolution.  

    .PARAMETER Overwrite
        Specifies a destination exist then overwrite it without prompt. 

    .PARAMETER FixedSize
        Set fixed size and do not try to scale the aspect ratio. 

    .PARAMETER RemoveSource
        Remove source file after conversion. 

    .EXAMPLE
        PS C:\> Get-ChildItem 'P:\test\*.jpg' | Set-ImageSize -Destination "p:\test2" -WidthPx 300 -HeightPx 375 -Verbose
        VERBOSE: Image 'P:\test\00001.jpg' was resize from 236x295 to 300x375 and save in 'p:\test2\00001.jpg'
        VERBOSE: Image 'P:\test\00002.jpg' was resize from 236x295 to 300x375 and save in 'p:\test2\00002.jpg'
        VERBOSE: Image 'P:\test\00003.jpg' was resize from 236x295 to 300x375 and save in 'p:\test2\00003.jpg'

    .NOTES
        Author: Michal Gajda
        Blog  : http://commandlinegeeks.com/
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess=$True,
        ConfirmImpact="Low"
    )]      
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias("Image")]    
        [String[]]$FullName,
        [String]$Destination = $(Get-Location),
        [Switch]$Overwrite,
        [Int]$WidthPx,
        [Int]$HeightPx,
        [Int]$DPIWidth,
        [Int]$DPIHeight,
        [Switch]$FixedSize,
        [Switch]$RemoveSource
    )
    Begin
    {
        [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
        #[void][reflection.assembly]::loadfile( "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll")
    }   
    Process
    {
        Foreach($ImageFile in $FullName)
        {
            If(Test-Path $ImageFile)
            {
                $OldImage = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $ImageFile
                $OldWidth = $OldImage.Width
                $OldHeight = $OldImage.Height               
                if($WidthPx -eq $Null)
                {
                    $WidthPx = $OldWidth
                }
                if($HeightPx -eq $Null)
                {
                    $HeightPx = $OldHeight
                }               
                if($FixedSize)
                {
                    $NewWidth = $WidthPx
                    $NewHeight = $HeightPx
                }
                else
                {
                    if($OldWidth -lt $OldHeight)
                    {
                        $NewWidth = $WidthPx
                        [int]$NewHeight = [Math]::Round(($NewWidth*$OldHeight)/$OldWidth)

                        if($NewHeight -gt $HeightPx)
                        {
                            $NewHeight = $HeightPx
                            [int]$NewWidth = [Math]::Round(($NewHeight*$OldWidth)/$OldHeight)
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $NewHeight = $HeightPx
                        [int]$NewWidth = [Math]::Round(($NewHeight*$OldWidth)/$OldHeight)

                        if($NewWidth -gt $WidthPx)
                        {
                            $NewWidth = $WidthPx
                            [int]$NewHeight = [Math]::Round(($NewWidth*$OldHeight)/$OldWidth)
                        }                       
                    }
                }
                $ImageProperty = Get-ItemProperty $ImageFile                
                $SaveLocation = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath ($ImageProperty.Name)
                If(!$Overwrite)
                {
                    If(Test-Path $SaveLocation)
                    {
                        $Title = "A file already exists: $SaveLocation"                         
                        $ChoiceOverwrite = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Overwrite"
                        $ChoiceCancel = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Cancel"
                        $Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($ChoiceCancel, $ChoiceOverwrite)     
                        If(($host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $null, $Options, 1)) -eq 0)
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Image '$ImageFile' exist in destination location - skiped"
                            Continue
                        } #End If ($host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $null, $Options, 1)) -eq 0
                    } #End If Test-Path $SaveLocation
                } #End If !$Overwrite                   
                $NewImage = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $NewWidth,$NewHeight
                $Graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($NewImage)
                $Graphics.InterpolationMode = [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode]::HighQualityBicubic
                $Graphics.DrawImage($OldImage, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight) 

                $ImageFormat = $OldImage.RawFormat
                $OldImage.Dispose()
                if($DPIWidth -and $DPIHeight)
                {
                    $NewImage.SetResolution($DPIWidth,$DPIHeight)
                } #End If $DPIWidth -and $DPIHeight

                $NewImage.Save($SaveLocation,$ImageFormat)
                $NewImage.Dispose()
                Write-Verbose "Image '$ImageFile' was resize from $($OldWidth)x$($OldHeight) to $($NewWidth)x$($NewHeight) and save in '$SaveLocation'"             
                If($RemoveSource)
                {
                    Remove-Item $Image -Force
                    Write-Verbose "Image source '$ImageFile' was removed"
                } #End If $RemoveSource
            }
        }
    } #End Process  
    End{}
}
```

Comment: Your script appears to have a typo: `Convert-ImgageType -> Convert-ImageType`

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but that is in fact the name of the module. This is a working script, I just need it to maintain the folder structure.

Comment: It seems the `Set-ImageSize` cmdlet defined in `Set-ImageSize.ps1` file is not copying/moving the files to the destination folder in the way you would like. Without showing the code in that file, there is no way of teling what you should change there.. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57009859/edit) your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: @Theo I have updated with the Set-ImageSize code

Comment: I worked out my own way but if your answer works I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oder to make it do what you want, namely keep the folder structure from the source images in the destination directory, I have edited the `Set-ImageSize` function.
It now has an extra (optional) parameter called `$SourcePath`.
Using that, it is possible to determine the folder structure for the destination.
Since the `$SourcePath` parameter is optional, not using that parameter in the function call, the resulting resized images are all saved in the same `Destination` folder.

This also means you need to change the calling of the function somewhat to make that happen.
First of all, you need to make sure the `-Destination` points to some other folder than the source of the files. Really nothing new, but that is a mistake you originally made.

Anyway, first the adapted function

```
function Set-ImageSize {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Resize image file.

    .DESCRIPTION
        The Set-ImageSize cmdlet to set new size of image file.

    .PARAMETER FullName
        Specifies an image file. 

    .PARAMETER SourcePath
        Optional. If used, the function creates the same folder structure in the Destination path
        to save the resized images. When not used, the resized images are all saved in the Destination folder.

    .PARAMETER Destination
        Specifies a destination of resized file. Default is current location (Get-Location).

    .PARAMETER WidthPx
        Specifies a width of image in px. 

    .PARAMETER HeightPx
        Specifies a height of image in px.      

    .PARAMETER DPIWidth
        Specifies a vertical resolution. 

    .PARAMETER DPIHeight
        Specifies a horizontal resolution.  

    .PARAMETER Overwrite
        Specifies a destination exist then overwrite it without prompt. 

    .PARAMETER FixedSize
        Set fixed size and do not try to scale the aspect ratio. 

    .PARAMETER RemoveSource
        Remove source file after conversion. 

    .EXAMPLE
        PS C:\> Get-ChildItem 'P:\test\*.jpg' | Set-ImageSize -Destination "p:\test2" -WidthPx 300 -HeightPx 375 -Verbose
        VERBOSE: Image 'P:\test\00001.jpg' was resize from 236x295 to 300x375 and save in 'p:\test2\00001.jpg'
        VERBOSE: Image 'P:\test\00002.jpg' was resize from 236x295 to 300x375 and save in 'p:\test2\00002.jpg'
        VERBOSE: Image 'P:\test\00003.jpg' was resize from 236x295 to 300x375 and save in 'p:\test2\00003.jpg'

    .NOTES
        Author: Michal Gajda
        Edited: Theo
        Blog  : http://commandlinegeeks.com/
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess=$True,
        ConfirmImpact="Low"
    )]      
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias("Image")]    
        [String[]]$FullName,
        [string]$SourcePath = $null,
        [String]$Destination = $(Get-Location),
        [Switch]$Overwrite,
        [Int]$WidthPx,
        [Int]$HeightPx,
        [Int]$DPIWidth,
        [Int]$DPIHeight,
        [Switch]$FixedSize,
        [Switch]$RemoveSource
    )
    Begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    }   
    Process {
        foreach($ImageFile in $FullName) {
            if (Test-Path $ImageFile -PathType Leaf) {
                $OldImage = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $ImageFile
                $OldWidth = $OldImage.Width
                $OldHeight = $OldImage.Height               
                if (!$WidthPx) { $WidthPx = $OldWidth }
                if (!$HeightPx) { $HeightPx = $OldHeight }               
                if ($FixedSize) {
                    $NewWidth  = $WidthPx
                    $NewHeight = $HeightPx
                }
                else {
                    if($OldWidth -lt $OldHeight) {
                        $NewWidth = $WidthPx
                        [int]$NewHeight = [Math]::Round(($NewWidth*$OldHeight)/$OldWidth)
                        if($NewHeight -gt $HeightPx) {
                            $NewHeight = $HeightPx
                            [int]$NewWidth = [Math]::Round(($NewHeight*$OldWidth)/$OldHeight)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $NewHeight = $HeightPx
                        [int]$NewWidth = [Math]::Round(($NewHeight*$OldWidth)/$OldHeight)
                        if($NewWidth -gt $WidthPx) {
                            $NewWidth = $WidthPx
                            [int]$NewHeight = [Math]::Round(($NewWidth*$OldHeight)/$OldWidth)
                        }                       
                    }
                }
                # most changes made here
                $imageFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($ImageFile)

                if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SourcePath)) {
                    # save in the destination path
                    $SaveFilePath = $Destination
                    $SaveFileName = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $imageFileName
                }
                else {
                    # keep directory structure
                    $imageFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($ImageFile).Substring($SourcePath.Length)
                    $SaveFilePath  = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $imageFilePath
                    $SaveFileName  = Join-Path -Path $SaveFilePath -ChildPath $imageFileName
                }

                # create the destination in $SaveFilePath if it does not already exist
                if (!(Test-Path -Path $SaveFilePath)) {
                    New-Item -Path $SaveFilePath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
                }

                if (!$Overwrite) {
                    if (Test-Path $SaveFileName -PathType Leaf) {
                        # are you sure you want to get this confirmation dialog every time?
                        $Title = "A file already exists: $SaveFileName"                         
                        $ChoiceOverwrite = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Overwrite"
                        $ChoiceCancel    = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Cancel"
                        $Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($ChoiceCancel, $ChoiceOverwrite)     
                        if (($host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $null, $Options, 1)) -eq 0) {
                            Write-Verbose "Image '$ImageFile' already exist in destination location - skipped"
                            Continue
                        }
                    }
                }                  
                $NewImage = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $NewWidth,$NewHeight
                $Graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($NewImage)
                $Graphics.InterpolationMode = [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode]::HighQualityBicubic
                $Graphics.DrawImage($OldImage, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight) 

                $ImageFormat = $OldImage.RawFormat
                $OldImage.Dispose()

                if ($DPIWidth -and $DPIHeight){
                    $NewImage.SetResolution($DPIWidth,$DPIHeight)
                }

                $NewImage.Save($SaveFileName, $ImageFormat)
                $NewImage.Dispose()

                Write-Verbose "Image '$ImageFile' was resized from $($OldWidth)x$($OldHeight) to $($NewWidth)x$($NewHeight) and saved as '$SaveFileName'"             
                if ($RemoveSource) {
                    Remove-Item $ImageFile -Force
                    Write-Verbose "Image source file '$ImageFile' was removed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    End{}
}
```

Now for the function call:

```
param([String]$src, [string]$dest, [switch]$keepSubFolders)

Import-Module '\Convert-ImgageType.ps1'
Import-Module '\Set-ImageSize.ps1'

Get-ChildItem "$src\*" -include *.tif -Recurse | Convert-ImgageType -Destination $src\* -Verbose
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

if ($keepSubFolders) {
    # to keep the folder structure, you need to use the -SourcePath parameter
    Get-ChildItem "$src\*.jpg" -File -Recurse | Set-ImageSize -SourcePath $src -Destination $dest -WidthPx 9000 -HeightPx 6000 -Verbose
}
else {
    Get-ChildItem "$src\*.jpg" -File -Recurse | Set-ImageSize -Destination $dest -WidthPx 9000 -HeightPx 6000 -Verbose
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
# you could also use the -RemoveSource switch on the Set-ImageSize function..
Remove-Item "$src\*.jpg" -Verbose
```

<sup>Note: I have not tested the `Convert-ImgageType` function..</sup>